# Loop over array kinda automation

Tags: einstein-analytics, tableau-crm, crm-analytics

I came to a tricky calculation: I need to identify dates 30 days apart from each other, and it's tricky because when a row doesn't fit 30 days rule the calculation for next row should not include this row but instead look and the row before and so on.
Example:
01.01.2023 - start
01.02.2023 - positive
28.02.2023 - negative
01.03.2023 - positive
Neither lag or calculation of days since start date won't tell me that fourth row should be positive. In order to do that negative row #3 must be excluded and lag() or prevvalue calculated from new array where row #2 now goes right before #4 and then it will return positive for #4, and this can go indefinitely like there could be 50-100 rows like row #3 which should be ignored.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.